# Working out annual income

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a problem that states

> The state income tax where Kristin lives charges at the rate of $p\%$
>   of the first $\$28000$ annual income plus $(p+2)\%$ of any amount
>   above $\$28000$. Kristin noticed that state income tax she paid
>   amounted amounted to $(p+0.25)\%$ of her annual income. What's her
>   annual income?

So the way i see it, the first part of the problem states $\frac{p}{100} \cdot 28000 = x$, but I fail to see how this gives me anything solvable. I'd appreciate if someone could walk me through this problem.

Comment: Well, since $p+.25>p$ it must be the case that she made more than $28000$.  Therefore, I suggest assigning a variable, $y$ for instance, to the amount she made over $28000$.  Now, do the computation using $y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say Kristin makes $k$ dollars. Try setting an equation for yourself. When you're done, the equation is also shown below:

> $$\frac{p}{100} \times 28000 + \frac{p+2}{100} \times (k - 28000) = \frac{p+0.25}{100} k$$

Now solve for $k$.

Answer (score 1):

Same idea as parts arithmetic: $$\begin{array}{c|c|c}p+2 &&.25\\\hline &p+.25&\\\hline p&&1.75\end{array}$$ scaling up the RHS to integers gives 1 part at $p+2$ for every 7 of $p$ leading the amount above 28000 to be 4000. So in total she made 32000.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what's going on here.

Comment: It's called alligation used in parts arithmetic of a whole for equal sized parts. Basically you're forming a weighted average. In this case the total difference of the parts needs to equal. RHS is are the weights. $$((p+2)-(p+.25))\cdot .25=((p+.25)-(p))\cdot 1.75$$

Comment: @Vocaloidas, are you still confused ?

Answer (score 0):

m = her year's income.  Does
(p/100 + .25)m = 280p + (p + 2)(m - 28000)/10)?